# Combine 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I am writing a program that print out the merged sequence, let assume that only two inputs. After printing a sequence, a blank line is printed. Also, the program prints the merged array with one string per line. The size of array is not more than 10. Here is the code i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo {
    public static int readInput(Scanner myScanner, String[] input) {
        boolean streamEnded = false;
        int index = 0;

        while (!streamEnded && myScanner.hasNext()) {

            String value = myScanner.nextLine();

            if (value.length() == 0)  {
                streamEnded = true;
                input[index] = value;
            } else {
                input[index] = value;
                index++;

            }
        } 
    return index;

    }
    public static void printArray(String[] values, int size) {
            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
                System.out.println(values[index]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 10;
        String[] input1 = new String[size];
        String[] input2 = new String[size];
        String[] merge = new String[size*2];

        Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        readInput(aScanner, input1);

        readInput (aScanner, input2);

        readInput (aScanner, merge);

        for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input1[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input2[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < merge.length; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                merge[i] = input1[i / 2];
                            System.out.println(store[i]);
            } else {
                merge[i] = input2[i / 2];
                            System.out.println(store[i]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My input:

```
1

2

3

4


5

6

7

8
```

So the output is supposed to be:

```
1

5

2

6

3

7

4

8
```

This is my output. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks

```
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8

1
2
3
4

null
null
null
null
null
5
6
7
8
null
null
null
null
null
null
1
6
3
8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:47)

null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: +1 Best homework question ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following:

```
  if(i % 2 == 0) {
                merge[i] = input1[i/2];
            } else {
                merge[i] = input2[i/2];
            }
```

For The updated code,

```
readInput(aScanner, input1);
```

should become

```
int index1 = readInput(aScanner, input1);
```

For all readInputs and then output loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(input1[i]);
        }
```

should become

```
 for (int i = 0; i < index1; i++) {
            System.out.println(input1[i]);
        }
```

for all output loops (Note that you need to use different index variable for all 3 inputs and loops i.e. index1, index2 and index3.

Comment: Thanks for help, however i still get the wrong output. My input1 was 1 2 3 4 5 and input2 was 6 7 8 9 10, and the merge was 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5. It is supposed to be 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10. Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: It was my mistake in the code. I have updated the code.

Comment: I got it right. Thanks very much. I still do get the null in my output. You have any idea to fix it?

Comment: It could be due to empty lines at end of file.

Comment: is it supposed to be like every time the input is less than 10 then null will show in the output?

Comment: I am not sure. If you update your code I can have a look at it :)

Comment: The problem is with the for loop for printing the input array. It is iterating from 0 to size-1, where size is a constant. Instead, you may like to iterate fro 0 to index where index-1 is returned from readInput.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i just updated my code, i added another method called printArray, but i still get the problem. Any idea? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the correct code, but this should get you thinking in the right direction.  Here's part of your code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < merge.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            merge[i] = input1[i];
        } else {
            merge[i] = input2[i];
        }
```

Is there any way this code can ever put `input2[2]` (for example) in the output?  The only way you'd ever use `input2[2]` is if `i==2`.  But then `i%2 == 0` so only the first branch of the `if` ever gets executed.  Similarly, can `input1[3]` ever get used?